# DirectX include and library directories in VC++

Tags: visual-c++, directx

I am getting the following error:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'd3dx11.lib'
```

I think it may be the result of incorrectly setting up the directX directories.

For both include and library directories I simply pasted the location of the corresponding SDK folders like this:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Lib
```

into the include and library directories pages respectively.

Are there additional steps I need to take? Did I set it up wrong initially? I apologize if the answer is incredibly simple, I have never needed to modify these settings before.

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Express

Comment: Is the `d3dx11.lib` inside of the `Lib` folder that you've set up?

Comment: Wow, I just realized that the correct folder was this: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Lib\x86, and not this:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Lib\

Comment: I knew it was something simple, thanks